# NZEC in Edit distance code

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

SPOJ is giving NZEC exception in my solution for the problem ==> http://www.spoj.com/problems/EDIST/

My solution is ==>

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

class EDIST {

    public static int trans(String a, String b, int i, int j, Map<String, Integer> m)
    {
        if(m.containsKey(i+" "+j))
            return m.get(i+" "+j);
        if(i==a.length())
            m.put(i+" "+j, b.length()-j);                   
        else if(j==b.length())
            m.put(i+" "+j, a.length()-i);
        else if(a.charAt(i)==b.charAt(j))
            m.put(i+" "+j, trans(a,b,i+1,j+1, m));
        else 
            m.put(i+" "+j, 1+ Math.min(trans(a,b,i,j+1, m),Math.min(trans(a,b,i+1,j+1, m), trans(a,b,i+1,j, m)))); //I, R and D;
        return m.get(i+" "+j); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        while(t--!=0)
        {
            String a = in.next();
            String b = in.next();
            Map<String, Integer> map = new  HashMap<String, Integer>();
            System.out.println(trans(a,b,0,0,map));
        }
        in.close();
    }

}
```

geeksforgeeks(http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-5-edit-distance/) and my logic is same but still i am getting NZEC error.
I am using HashMap for storing intermediate results.I have tested my code for large input but still, i do not why am i getting NZEC on spoj.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from getting uncaught exception, spoj also gives NZEC error if you forgot to remove **package yourpackagename;** from your code before submitting in spoj (although the code you added here doesn't contain this line but I still recommend you to verify this in your actual submission).

I was getting NZEC error in different question for this reason.